# Allow phone finger scrolling

Tags: css

I'm working on this site:

http://miketest.best/

But for some reason, the finger scrolling up and down isn't working on phones. Tried overflow-y: scroll in the .slide-container > section but it isn't working. Desktop mousewheel and arrows works.

What can I be missing? I just want the contents in each section element to be able to scroll through on phones and computers. Preferably with the side scroller hidden.

```
.slide-container {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    -ms-scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}

.slide-container > section {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    -ms-flex-negative: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    position: relative;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    overflow: scroll;
    overscroll-behavior-y: contain;
    padding: 100px 1em 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running WordPress, it is most likely a plugin that doesn't play nicely with the others or with your theme.

- try switching your theme to one of the official Automattic themes like TwentyEighteen or others. See if that fixes the problem.
- disable all plugins, then one by one, re-enable them, checking each time to see if the problem comes back.

If neither of those approaches work, you should ask in the official [WP Support](https://wordpress.org/support/) forums.